# Сравнение смайликов в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста почему два разных смайлика в базе видит как один и тот же?

Запрос1 - где ищу дубликаты:

```
SELECT brand,title,author,buyer_rating,review_content, COUNT(*) AS dublicate
FROM simba_dublicate
GROUP BY brand,title,author,buyer_rating,review_content
HAVING dublicate > 1
```

Результат запроса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запрос 2, чтоб увидеть что дубликата только два а не три:

```
SELECT *
FROM simba_dublicate
WHERE author = 'Daddy'
```

Результат в табличке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что это за клиент базы данных?

Comment: Использую HeidiSQL

Comment: там на фото видно, что клиент вообще не воспринимает смайлики как символы. То есть, из клиента в сервер уходит строка " '?'='?' " - что, конечно же, правда. Может именно в этом дело?

Comment: `collate` там напишите какой-нить ему

Comment: Кстати в таблице смайлы отображаются нормально, сейчас добавлю скрин

Comment: вы лучше бы исходный текст запроса добавили. зы: у меня в heidi нормально работает. другие правда эмотиконы какие-то

Comment: Есть, вот так таблица создана, данные импортил с csv

Comment: текст `SELECT`, а не create. зы: зачем вам поля типа TEXT, а не varchar ?

Comment: Я не знал, сколько будет символов у некоторых полей, выбрал TEXT, сейчас добавлю селект

Comment: @teran Обновил, добавил запросы. У меня сейчас почему-то показывает что есть три дубликата, хотя только две строки из трех, с одним смайлом...

Comment: Переименуйте, что ли, тему в "Сравнение смайликов в MySQL" - а то в нынешнем виде она не соответствует вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За сравнение символов (и пофиг, буквы это или там смайлы) отвечает COLLATION. Укажите выполнять сравнение с использованием BINARY COLLATION:

```
SELECT brand,
       title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_bin,
       author,
       buyer_rating,
       review_content, 
       COUNT(*) AS dublicate
FROM simba_dublicate
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
HAVING dublicate > 1
```

Откорректируйте COLLATION, чтобы соответствовать текущему CHARSET. При необходимости укажите COLLATION и для других полей.

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48c84781c522d6128699d1d12a4a42dc)

Comment: Спасибо. Я вот поставил всем полям COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin и оно заработало!))